# javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

i am getting exception javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed in return statement, i am using spring JPA.

```
 StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder(querystat);
    System.out.println("startDate--->" + startDate);
    Query query = 
  getEntityManager().createQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
    System.out.println("query.list();--->"
            + query.getResultList().size());
 return query.getResultList();
```

any one have idea on this issue?

Comment: Please share all of your code.

Comment: Did you try taking query.getResultList() in a local list variable?

Comment: You are probably missing the @Transactional annotation / transactional setup.

Comment: Attach a debugger with beakpoint on "javax.persistence.PersistenceException" exception and then check the root cause of this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responses..i have added transactionTemplate in service class its working.below is the working code..

```
return transactionTemplate
    .execute(new TransactionCallback<List<?>>() {
        public List<?> doInTransaction(
                TransactionStatus status) {
            return dao.monthReportQuery(startDate, endDate);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please have a look at the @Transactional way of doing things. It leads to better code then the usage of TransactionalTemplate...I would not use the Template way of doing things (transactions buta lso others) unless otherwise not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The public method calling the code needs to be annotated with [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html).

Further, the processing of `@Transactional` needs to be activated. This might or might not be already active.  It can be activated using the [@EnableTransactionManagement](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html).

The method annotated with `@Transactional` shall not be called from the same class.